# Optimizing a MySQL Subselect Update

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time getting this update to run in a reasonable amount of time. Notice - events_copy is a copy of events since I couldn't update the table I was querying one.

```
update events 
    set dummy = 1 
    where event_id in 
    (select event_id 
        from events_copy 
        join qualifiers using (event_id) 
        where type = 10);
```

I thought this might be an alternative as a "create table x from ...", but the group by takes way too long.

```
select 
    events.*, 
    if(type = 10, 1, 0) 
    from events 
    left join qualifiers using (event_id) 
    group by event_id;
```

Comment: Where table is the `type` field in? I may be able to make my answer even faster.

Comment: @ZaneBien type is in qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` in your update rather than subquery:

```
UPDATE events a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT event_id
    FROM events_copy
    INNER JOIN qualifiers USING (event_id)
    WHERE type = 10
) b ON a.event_id = b.event_id
SET a.dummy = 1
```

The reason why it's slow is because the subquery is executing and performing a join for each row in your `events` table. Instead, the subselect will execute once.

Comment: Brilliant. And thanks for the clarification on why it was slow in the first place.